# Office web apps supported file extensions list

Tags: office-365, 2016, office-web-apps

Is there any definitive list of file extension that opens in O365 web apps/Office online?
E.g: docx, doc, ppt, pptx, xls, xlsx, ...

Update:
I noticed that onenote and visio extension(.one, and .vsd) is also supported, is there any official list from Microsoft as I need to make a whitelist out of these extensions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supported files for viewing:

- Word files: .doc, .dot, .dotx, .docx, .docm, .odt
- Powerpoint: .pot, .potm, .pps, .ppsm, .ppt, .pptm, .pptx, ppsx, .odp
- Excel .xls, .xlsx, .xlsm, .xlsb, .ods

Supported files for viewing, editing and annotating:

- Word: .docx, .docm, .odt
- Excel: .xlsx, .xlsm, .xlsb, .ods
- Powerpoint: .pptx, ppsx, .odp

[Which File Types Are Supported by Office Online?](https://support.edmodo.com/hc/en-us/articles/210209948-Which-File-Types-Are-Supported-by-Office-Online-)

Comment: I noticed that onenote and visio extension(.one, and .vsd) is also supported, is there any official list from Microsoft as I need to make a whitelist out of these extensions. Thanks